# Composer and Yii

Tags: php, yii, dependencies, composer-php

I'm using composer as my dependency manager and since I need to develop with Yii Framework I added it to my composer.json file, so it looks like this:

```
//other properties...
"require": {
    //other dependencies...
    "yiisoft/yii": "dev-master"
}
```

Composer.json is ok, Yii downloaded correctly, but there is a feature I think composer misses.
My yii directory now is full of "rubbish", demo folders, build files bla bla that I don't really need.
There is a way to tell composer to keep only some directory and throw away the others?

Answer (score 3):

With composer we work in a different way. With composer our application take care only of its code. In fact, if you kork with git, you must add yii folder to .gitignore couse is not your application folder. This is the symfony way.

What about Yii!? First of all I suggest you to start yii projects with:

```
$ composer create-project yiisoft/yii path/to/your/project
```

This is the Yii way to work with yii and composer. After that, when you finish to dowload yii, composer ask you if you want to keep or not yii's git files. You can simply say no, and remove manually these files. You can also try to fork yiisoft/yii and improve this behavior so this removing stuffs will happen automatically.

Comment: I've a custom application structure using Yii, with vendor directory for my dependencies (there will go yiisoft/yii and yes it is git ignored) and app directory for my "sub-app" like backend, frontend etc.. (very similar to yii2 structure). However i just want to keep only the framework directory instead of the entire repository.

Comment: Not exists a repository with only framework. Just fork 1.1.14 project and remove all stuffs you dont need. It's easy.

Comment: using an unofficial repository seems to be a bad solution, i mean it's ok only I fork myself the official and remove all "useless" stuff, then I'll depend on my own repository!

Comment: That is ANTI-pattern on how to use package dependency software. Its useful only when it can manage dependency of already existing projects. So 1) Get Composer 2) Get Yii 3) Create app should be executed only ONCE. And 1) Update your app source code 2) Update dependencies, should be main use.

Comment: Yes, I have my own project with a composer that includes yii and some extensions. I do not create yii application with create-project. It make sense update my answer. I invite you to take a look at https://github.com/sensorario/communityii @przemo_li

Comment: I do not know composer well enought to understand communityii structure :D. Is that template structure for projects? Nice, but again. Usefull only at the beginning of the lifecycle of given project. (Which is least important job for composer) But hey, If I'm wrong, just explain it.

Comment: "Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install them in your project for you."

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, so I ended up [repackaging Yii](https://packagist.org/packages/square1-io/yii-framework) so that it only contains the framework folder. It reduces the package by ~10Mb. Here's a [link to the github repo](https://github.com/square1-io/yii-framework).

Just add the following to your composer.json file.

```
{
    "require": {
        "square1-io/yii-framework": "1.1.14"
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
$ composer install
```

I've thrown up a blog post about it: http://blog.square1.io/post/60830077608/yii-1-1-14-via-composer

Comment: it's a solution but it just force me to repackage yii at every new release, however +1 for your solution.

Comment: How can we get version than 1.1.14?