# How to run the yii after installation in ubuntu?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have installed the yii framework successfully.I have installed it via `composer`. The location of my folder is `/var/www/yii-test/advanced/.`
I have opened my terminal and executed the below command.

```
cd /var
cd www
php /var/www/yii-test/advance/advanced/yiic webapp myyii
```

after executing this I got the below error.

```
Could not open input file: /var/www/yii-test/advance/advanced/yiic
```

so what is the sequence of executing the command and is this right way to setup the `yii`.
`myyii` is the folder name where I will keep the my yii application.

Comment: I guess you're using `Yii2` and not `Yii`

Comment: I follow the steps from their official site.and installed the advance template.

Comment: refer this: http://www.square1.io/blog/yii-1-1-14-via-composer/33 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648066/composer-and-yii

Comment: Maybe you just misspelled path. Check `/advance/advanced/` part.

Comment: run `init` or `php init` command in console in project directory

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command `init` or `php init` (I don't remember which) in the root path. In advance projects you have to start your **environment**.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can directly follow the steps from Step-7 to Step 10.

1)install curl.
sudo apt-get install curl

2)install php5-cli package
sudo apt-get install php5-cli

3) install the php5-mysql package
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

4) install  php5-mcrypt package.
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

5) activate php5-mcrypt package.
sudo php5enmod mcrypt

6) install php5-gd package
sudo apt-get install php5-gd

7) install Composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

8) install it globally
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

9)Move to your localhost web root folder
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/

10)To install 

a)basic template
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic
Type in url: localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/

b)advanced template
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced
Type in url: localhost/yii2-app-advanced/web/
```

Or, Check This Link [Install Yii2](http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=4) To Install.

Cheers !